# Yeoman Favicon Still Present After Icon Reference and Cache Clearing on Firefox

Tags: html, yeoman, favicon

I used Yeoman to set up my app initially and I have been having issues getting rid of the favicon ever since then. 
First, I created a reference in my index.html file for the correct image, like so:

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" sizes="16x16 24x24 
                                             32x32 48x48 64x64                  
                                             96x96 128x128 192x192" 
     href="img/favicon.ico">
```

I cleared the cache for all my browsers and I am still having a problem with Firefox. 
It does not show up on Chrome, IE or Safari. I looked up the favicon.ico file generated that shows Yeoman and noticed that it is on my root directory (unlike the default favicon image), so I added an image with the same name and directory location that is another copy of my default image. 
Unfortunately, every time I arrive at the app on firefox I see the Yeoman favicon once again. If I refresh the page, the default image shows as expected.

Does anyone know what I could do to rid myself of this Yeoman favicon forever?